# How to Change my Excel Hyperlink Path of Whole Column

Tags: excel, hyperlink, filepath

I have maintain a EXCEL worksheet for recruitment like CV details. I have also included hyperlinks for folders containing specific C Vs like Engineers C Vs in Engineer folder and all the folders in one Recruitment Folder. there is one column in sheet with the name resume and there are all the hyperlinks of Respective designated CV in a row. My folder is Placed in C:/user/documents/recruitment/name of the folder designated folder/Specific CV

My Problem is that know i have to share this sheet with office staff on network and now placed folder in  shared folder O:/Bashir/recruitment/  but placing this my hyperlink path changes with it. so what can i do to change hyperlink path for my thousand of C Vs  hyperlinks.

Sorry my English is not very good.

Comment: as @Frankenmint pointed out, i might have got it incorrectly, do you need to change the hyperlinks paths so they point to the folder  on "O:\" drive? or do they need to point to each user's specific folder once they download it?

Answer (score 0):

tested and works:

```
Sub replace_HL()

Dim str As String
Const strOriginal = "C:/user/documents/recruitment/"
Const strNew = "O:/Bashir/recruitment/"

For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")

  On Error Resume Next
  str = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
  cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Replace(str, strOriginal, strNew, , , vbTextCompare)

Next

End Sub
```

assign whichever string you are looking for to `strOriginal`, new path string to `strNew` and change the `Range` bit from `A1:A100` to whatever range you need to check. Please note i have also included `On Error Resume Next` in case the code comes around a cell without a hyperlink it will just skip it. Also, double check the slashes in your string are facing the right way, as in your example you have forward slash - "/" and file paths are built with back slash - "\"

Comment: his problem is that each link depends on the username of the recipient, then your solution would need to be run by the recipient in order to work.

Comment: thanks a lot guys for helping me out. O drive path changing is ok but i have also different names for CVs like every Cv is differently named so what should i do for this thing .

Comment: I wanted to change my HL path to O: Drive and Change complete path upto the name of the Cv file.

Comment: I still can't understand what do you want to do to all the different names of CVs?

Answer (score 0):

i might have failed to understand what exactly is required, your English is in fact not that clear, as pointed out by Frankenmint, the quite opposite action might be in fact required - for users to be able to change the hyperlinks from "O:\" drive to their local documents path, this is also possible with the slightly modified below code:

```
Sub replace_HL()

Dim str As String, strOriginal As String, strNew As String
Const strOriginal = "O:\Bashir\recruitment\"
strNew = Environ("userprofile") & "\documents\recruitment\"

For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")

  On Error Resume Next
  str = cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address
  cell.Hyperlinks(1).Address = Replace(str, strOriginal, strNew, , , vbTextCompare)

Next
```

End Sub

`Environ("userprofile")` will pick up the Windows assigned relative path to user's local folder, i.e. if your name is "John Smith" it will return your assigned user folder "C:\users\John Smith"